# How to determine if a point is inside a polygon using Oracle Spatial Java API?

Tags: java, oracle-spatial

First I tried:

```
public static boolean isInPolygon(java.awt.geom.Point2D point) {
        // ...
        // ... build prepared statement
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        STRUCT geoStruct = (STRUCT) rs.getObject("SDO_GEOMETRY_COLUMN");

        JGeometry geo = JGeometry.load(geoStruct);
        Shape shape = geo.createShape();
        return shape.contains(point);           
    }
```

This did not work, as `JGeometry.createShape()` returns a `java.awt.geom.GeneralPath` object, which does not have double precision, therefore `shape.contains(...)` returned wrong results around the edges of the polygon.

Then I tried using `JGeometry.createDoubleShape()` which returns a `oracle.spatial.util.SDODoubleGeneralPath` object instead:

```
// ...
JGeometry geo = JGeometry.load(geoStruct);
Shape shape = geo.createDoubleShape();
return shape.contains(point);
```

When the `contains` method is called, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.awt.geom.Curve.crossingsForPath(Ljava/awt/geom/PathIterator;DD)I
    at oracle.spatial.util.SDODoubleGeneralPath.contains(SDODoubleGeneralPath.java:498)
    at igea_html.test.Test.handleGeo(Test.java:258)
    at igea_html.test.Test.jgeometryTest(Test.java:204)
    at igea_html.test.Main.main(Main.java:74)
```

Apparently `SDODoubleGeneralPath` has some implementation issues if its `contains` method throws such an error.

Is there an alternative?

I would like to avoid implementing myself an algorithm for determining if a point is inside a polygon, I'd rather trust something already implemented from a reputable source.
I also cannot use the Oracle Spatial functions directly in the database due to a license restriction.

Obs.: My `isInPolygon` method uses Point2D as an argument, but it is ok if I have to use a point in the form of a `JGeometry` object in case the solution requires it.

**Further details as requested:**
Oracle version is 11g and I'm working on a web app that is supposed to validate geometrical data in the database. In particular, one of the validations involve checking if certain points and polygons are inside other polygons. The documentation I'm referencing is this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e11829/toc.htm
The architecture of those features is still a work in progress so the decision if this should be made by the web app itself or inside the database or some other method is still open. The second option was thrown aside due to license restrictions, the required functions, i.e. `SDO_RELATE`, are exclusive to Oracle Spatial in Oracle 11 apparently in contrast to Oracle 12 where they are available with just Oracle Locator.
**EDIT**: This is incorrect, as indicated by @Albert Godfrind below. `SDO_RELATE` and other spatial operators **are** supported by Oracle Locator 11 as indicated in Oracle's documentation, both in release 1 and 2:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_locator.htm#CFACCEEG
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_locator.htm#CFACCEEG

Also, the `JGeometry` class of the Java API for Oracle 11 does not contain methods such as `isInside()` or `anyInteract()` like it does on its Oracle 12 counterpart. Oracle 12 Java API docs: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/spajv/index.html?oracle/spatial/geometry/JGeometry.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say

> I also cannot use the Oracle Spatial functions directly in the database due to a license restriction.

That is not correct. All vector processing functions for 2D come for free with your database licenses. It is called **Oracle Locator**. See appendix B of the users guide for the fine print details of what Locator covers (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/spatl/oracle-locator.html#GUID-EC6DEA23-8FD7-4109-A0C1-93C0CE3D6FF2). Note that this is for 12.2. Older versions were more restrictive, but all come with the basic ability to do the geometry filtering you need.

The Oracle Spatial & Graph license complements the basic functions with support for things like 3D, rasters, networks, geocoding, visualization as well as semantic and property graphs.

Other than that, you can freely use the JAVA API (it comes with Oracle Locator). Note however that it exclusively works on `JGeometry` objects. In particular method `isInside()` will tell you whether one JGeometry object (your point) is fully contained inside another JGeometry object (your polygon). If you want points falling on the boundary of the polygon to also be returned, then use the `anyInteract()` method instead.

However if your main processing is in the database, then just use plain SQL with the `SDO_INSIDE` (or `SDO_ANYINTERACT` predicate to find all points that fall inside a polygon.

Can you say more about your actual use case ?

**EDIT**

Here is an example of using the SQL API. This is valid for all database releases, all the way back to 11gR1 and is covered by Oracle Locator (i.e. no need for any Spatial license).

In this example, I am using the following two tables:

A table containing the location of major US cities:

```
Name                                     Null?    Type
---------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
ID                                       NOT NULL NUMBER
CITY                                              VARCHAR2(42 CHAR)
POP90                                             NUMBER
RANK90                                            NUMBER
LOCATION                                          MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY
```

A table containing the shape of US states:

```
Name                                     Null?    Type
---------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
ID                                       NOT NULL NUMBER
STATE                                             VARCHAR2(26 CHAR)
STATE_ABRV                                        VARCHAR2(2 CHAR)
FIPSST                                            VARCHAR2(2 CHAR)
LANDSQMI                                          NUMBER
POPPSQMI                                          NUMBER
GEOM                                              MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY
```

The following query returns all cities in New York state:

```
select c.city, c.pop90
from us_cities c, us_states s
where s.state = 'New York'
and sdo_inside (c.location, s.geom) = 'TRUE';
```

which returns:

```
CITY                                POP90
------------------------------ ----------
New York                          7322564
Buffalo                            328123
Rochester                          231636
Yonkers                            188082
Syracuse                           163860
Albany                             101082

6 rows selected.
```

All you need is to submit this statement via JDBC and fetch the results. If you want to also return the location of the points (to highlight them on a map) then also include the `location` column. This you can interpret in your Java code via the Spatial Java API. Or you could also extract the coordinates from the points:

```
select c.city, c.pop90, c.location.sdo_point.x longitude, c.location.sdo_point.y latitude
from us_cities c, us_states s
where s.state = 'New York'
and sdo_inside (c.location, s.geom) = 'TRUE';

CITY                                POP90  LONGITUDE   LATITUDE
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
New York                          7322564 -73.943849    40.6698
Buffalo                            328123 -78.859684    42.8898
Rochester                          231636 -77.615838  43.168651
Yonkers                            188082 -73.867514  40.947033
Syracuse                           163860 -76.144067  43.041059
Albany                             101082 -73.799017   42.66575

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: It's a web app that interacts with geometrical objects in the database. One of the features is supposed to validate if certain objects are inside certain polygons (mainly points, but also other polygons).
Oracle version is 11g unfortunately and the documentation I'm using is https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e11829/toc.htm
Apparently there is no `isInside()` method.
My comment about the license was directly echoed from my manager, but I'll double check it since you mentioned that could not be the case.

Comment: Indeed, in Oracle 11g you need a Spatial license to use these functions: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/license.112/e47877/options.htm#DBLIC157
I'm just not 100% sure of this statement because I'm not sure how SDO_RELATE relates do SDO_GEOM.RELATE , for example, licensewise. It says in that link that SDO_GEOM.RELATE is exclusive to Oracle Spatial. Does that mean SDO_RELATE is as well?

Comment: Anyway, the question remains: how to do that with the Java API? As I said, I couldn't find the methods `isInside()` or `anyInteract()` in the JGeometry class. Apparently those are (understandably) exclusive to the Oracle 12 API: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/spajv/index.html?oracle/spatial/geometry/JGeometry.html

Comment: Let me answer this in stages

Comment: (1) You are correct that the java API in 12.x is much richer than the one one in 11.2 and before. I had not realized how much richer it is. That said, you can technically use the 12.x (12.2) version of the java library against 11.2 databases. The licensing aspects are fuzzier. The scope of Locator vs Spatial is more completely described in Appendix B of the Spatial Developer's Guide (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_locator.htm#SPATL340) and that explicitly mentions the ability to use the java API and explicitly points to the 11.2 version of the API.

Comment: (2) In 11.2 also the scope of Locator is narrower: it excludes some spatial processing functions: `SDO_GEOM.RELATE()` in particular is excluded. However it includes all spatial **predicates** including `SDO_RELATE` and its simpler to use variants (`SDO_INSIDE`, `SDO_CONTAINS`, ...). Those are used in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: (3) The question is really where is is more appropriate to run the filtering you want to do. Doing it in the application means reading **all** points from the database and comparing each and everyone of them against the polygon. That is unlikely to be efficient and unlikely to scale. The better approach is to send a SELECT statement to the database to do the filtering there and then (and no longer need to use the Spatial JAVA API at all). I edited my answer with an example.

Comment: Deep apologies for the super late mark as accepted answer. You have helped a lot, thank you.